# ionic routing not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What is the problem with this routing

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',      
      templateUrl: 'templates/appHome.html',
      controller: 'AppHomeController'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

Its not showing `appHome.html` by default.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Could be an error in AppHomeController.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

you should specify where is the `templateUrl` of the abstracted route,

```
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/sidemenu/menu.html',
        controller: 'menuController'
    })
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      }
    }
  });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

and also be sure that you had included `<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>` in your abstracted view.